# Can I enter data into the MySQL database using the Swift 2

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift2, xcode7

I have 3 textfield in my application which are the following:

- e-mail
- username
- password

I want to enter this data into the `MySQL` database using `Xcode swift`

Comment: which data base is are you used `SQLite` or `CoreData`

Comment: oh ok ok , canyou show your URL and params once

Comment: Do you want to connect MySQL server with swift code?

Comment: no i want to insert textfield data into mysql localhost server

Comment: @teko i have answered if you find it useful don't forget to upvote and acccept

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to connect MySql Server externally or your local my SQL database

Here is the way using this library
https://github.com/novi/mysql-swift

**How to make connection**

```
 let options = Options(host: "db.example.tokyo"...)
    let pool = ConnectionPool(options: options)

    let conn = try pool.getConnection() 
    conn.query("SELECT 1 + 2;")
    conn.release()
```

**How to get data from database**

```
 let rows: [User] = try pool.execute { conn in
        // The connection is held in this block
        try conn.query("SELECT * FROM users;") // And also it returns result to outside execute block
    }
```

For more refer the library documentation here

[Documentation](https://github.com/novi/mysql-swift/blob/master/README.md)